# How to put content on top page (css)

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm a newbie about css (as you can see how bad is my webpage) and I'm having problem to put some content at the center top of the page. In my webpage I also use bootstrap, because many people told me that it make easier creating nice css. The page is a `View` of CodeIgniter project, so, for this reason you will see some `Php` code:

Home_view.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css"></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('/Fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('/Fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js'); ?>"></script>

   <title>Private Area</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('home_view_style.css');?>"> 
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/icon-prof.png'); ?>">
   <h4>Benvenuto <!-- <?php echo $username; ?> --> </h4>
   <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
   <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" rel="group" href="http://www.istruzioneformazionelavoro.it/Engine/RAServeFile.php/f/corsi/84/Tabella_corsi_allegatoDD311.pdf">prova</a>
   </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="loader" style="margin-left: 300px;">

<div class="loader">

<?php echo form_open_multipart('materiale/inserisci');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile"  size="20" />

<br />
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
Nome<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nome"  size="20" />
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
Descrizione<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Descrizione"  size="20" />
</div>
<br />
<label for="tipo_libro"><input id="tipo_libro" type="radio" name="tipo" value="libro" checked/>Libro</label>
<br/>
<label for="tipo_guide"><input id="tipo_guide" type="radio" name="tipo" value="guide"/>Guida</label>
<br/>
<label for="tipo_video"><input id="tipo_video" type="radio" name="tipo" value="video"/>Video</label>
<br/>
<label for="tipo_animazioni"><input id="tipo_animazioni" type="radio" name="tipo" value="animazioni"/>Animazioni</label>
<br/>
<label for="tipo_registrazioni"><input id="tipo_registrazioni" type="radio" name="tipo" value="registrazioni"/>Registrazioni</label>
<br/>

<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Carica" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
</form>




  <div>
    <h3><span class="label label-success">Libri</span> </h3>
<?php  


echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";
echo "</br>";

 foreach ($libri as $row):
?>
            <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            </br>
                   <img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/book.png'); ?>" />
                   <a href="<?php  echo base_url($row['Url_suffix']) ?>"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?> </a>
             <a href="<?php  echo site_url('libro/elimina/'.$row['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/button_close.png'); ?>"/></a>
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
 endforeach;

       ?>
<?php
       echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
             ?>
</div>
</br>
</br>
<div>
    <h3><span class="label label-success">Guide</span> </h3>
<?php  


echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";
echo "</br>";

 foreach ($guide as $row):
?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            </br>
             <img src="<?php echo  base_url('Immagini/guide.png'); ?>" />
             <a href="<?php  echo  base_url('Uploads/10.pdf') ?>"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?> </a> 
             <a href="<?php  echo site_url('guida/elimina/'.$row['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/button_close.png'); ?>"/></a>
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
 endforeach;

       ?>
<?php
       echo "</tbody>";
          echo "</table>";
           ?>
</div>
</br>
</br>
<div>
    <h3><span class="label label-success">Video</span> </h3>
    <?php  


echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";
echo "</br>";

 foreach ($video as $row):
?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            </br>
             <img src="<?php echo  base_url('Immagini/video.png'); ?>" />
             <a href="<?php  echo  base_url('Uploads/10.pdf') ?>"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?> </a> 
             <a href="<?php  echo site_url('Video_c/elimina/'.$row['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/button_close.png'); ?>"/></a>
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
 endforeach;

       ?>
<?php
       echo "</tbody>";
          echo "</table>";
           ?>
</div>
</br>
</br>
<div>
    <h3><span class="label label-success">Animazioni</span></h3>
    <?php  


echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";
echo "</br>";

 foreach ($animazioni as $row):
?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            </br>
             <img src="<?php echo  base_url('Immagini/animazioni.png'); ?>" />
             <a href="<?php  echo  base_url('Uploads/10.pdf') ?>"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?> </a> 
             <a href="<?php  echo site_url('animazione/elimina/'.$row['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/button_close.png'); ?>"/></a>
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
 endforeach;

       ?>
<?php
       echo "</tbody>";
          echo "</table>";
           ?>
</div>
</br>
</br>
<div>
    <h3><span class="label label-success">Registrazioni</span> </h3>
    <?php  


echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";
echo "</br>";

 foreach ($registrazioni as $row):
?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
             <img src="<?php echo  base_url('immagini/video.png'); ?>" />
             <a href="<?php  echo  base_url('Uploads/10.pdf') ?>"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?> </a> 
             <a href="<?php  echo site_url('registrazione/elimina/'.$row['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/button_close.png'); ?>"/></a> 
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
 endforeach;

       ?>
<?php
       echo "</tbody>";
          echo "</table>";
           ?>
</div>
</br>
</br>
<div>
</div>


</div>
</div> <!-- end #container-->

 </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have something similar to this:
[image]

I tried many ways, for example I tried this:

```
#top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 23px;
text-align:center;
}
```

and the use into the `div` , but unfortunately with no results. I ask to have patience because I'm a newbie of css, and I'm having trouble to understand. In the end, if anyone can give me also aesthetic suggests I'll be happy, in this way I'll  grow even more.

Update 2:

home_view_style.css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url("immagini/Opedia_lab_Logged.png");
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Arial;
  font-size: 14px;

}



.btn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #84ae6a;
    border-color: #84ae6a;
    position:absolute;  // absolutely positioned
    right: 100%;

}
a{

  text-decoration: none;
}

#log {
    margin: 60px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#log {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
#log {
    margin: 20px;
    background: rgba(90,90,90,0.1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#side-nav {
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
#viewport.open #side-nav, #side-nav {
    width: 25%;
    left: 0px;
}
#side-nav {
    width: 40%;
    left: -40%;
}
#side-nav {
    width: 80%;
    left: -80%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.190,1.000,0.220,1.000);
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.190,1.000,0.220,1.000);
}
#side-nav {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#loader{  
     position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    font: 14px ,Arial;
    color: #5C5C5C;
    background: #F2FFED;
    padding: 10px;
}​


/*.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
*/
/*
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.inputs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


   .input.submit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  right: 70%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
*/
```

Comment: Though not professional in `CSS` try increasing `zindex` property.

Comment: i don't even see a top element in your page

Comment: First deploy this page in Peo HTML. Then slice this to Codeigniter

Comment: @sintakonte I deleted because it was not working: I created a div like this...

`<div id="container" style="margin-left: 300px;">

<div class="top">

<?php echo form_open_multipart('materiale/inserisci');?>`
.
.
.

Comment: @Abdulla I don't get what you are you telling me. Home_view.php is a View of codeigniter project. There are several parts because I need to put there, it is not my choice, I'm obliged because I take content from a DB, and controllers,ecc.

Comment: please show the extact script you are using without deleting anything otherwise it's difficult to help you

Comment: @sintakonte I update the code and I also add the `home_view_style.css ` that I'm using

Comment: which part of this would you like to have as a sticky header because i still dont see an area which is called "top" ;)

Comment: @sintakonte The part of area that I call "loader", I was wrong before, I should have read "top" somewhere. The part is "loader".